# Mantener conexiones continuas Firebase Cloud Functions Expressjs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, firebase, express

Buenas estoy por terminar de desarrollar un api, y ahora estoy viendo el tema de optimización. La api lo estoy desarrollando en un entorno administrado como es Firebase y con su servicio Cloud Functions, asimismo con ExpressJS. El problema reside que en su documentacion para mantener conexiones continuas exponen el siguiente código

```
const http = require('http');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// Setting the `keepAlive` option to `true` keeps
// connections open between function invocations
const agent = new http.Agent({keepAlive: true});

exports.myFunctions = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    req = http.request({
        host: '',
        port: 80,
        path: '',
        method: 'GET',
        agent: agent, // Holds the connection open after the first invocation
    }, res => {
        let rawData = '';
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', chunk => { rawData += chunk; });
        res.on('end', () => {
            response.status(200).send(`Data: ${rawData}`);
        });
    });
    req.on('error', e => {
        response.status(500).send(`Error: ${e.message}`);
    });
    req.end();
});
```

Pero en el caso de ExpressJS solo nos da la opcion de implementarlo asi:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

// Automatically allow cross-origin requests
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

// Add middleware to authenticate requests
app.use(myMiddleware);

// build multiple CRUD interfaces:
app.get('/:id', (req, res) => res.send(Widgets.getById(req.params.id)));
app.post('/', (req, res) => res.send(Widgets.create()));
app.put('/:id', (req, res) => res.send(Widgets.update(req.params.id, req.body)));
app.delete('/:id', (req, res) => res.send(Widgets.delete(req.params.id)));
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send(Widgets.list()));

// Expose Express API as a single Cloud Function:
exports.widgets = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

La finalidad de mantener conexión continuas es para no agotar la cuota de conexión. No he encontrado nada en la documentación que pueda ayudar en este caso.